# Boundedness of a solution of Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, elliptic-equations

Consider the equation $-\Delta u = f$ in a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^3$ with BC $u|_\Gamma=0$.

Let $f \in L^\infty$. Is it true that the weak solution $u \in L^\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The proof is based on a version of the weak maximum principle that is valid for weak solutions.  See, for example, Theorem 8.1 in Gilbarg and Trudinger.

Comment: How does it follow from Theorem 8.1? This theorem concerns equations without right hand side like Laplace equation.

Comment: As I think, it is proved in Theorem 8.15.